# iOS 17 UIImageView tintColor issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios17, tintcolor

Applying color picked from UIColorPickerViewController to UIImageview's tintColor(a color having kCGColorSpaceModelRGB ColorSpace),

then getting tintColor from that same UIImageView is always giving me gray color(a color having uiextendedgraycolorspace ColorSpace), this issue occured only in iOS 17

Opening UIColorPickerViewController code,

```
let colorPicker = UIColorPickerViewController()
            colorPicker.delegate = self
            colorPicker.dismissDelegate = self
            colorPicker.view.tag = viewTag
            colorPicker.selectedColor = selectedColor ?? .black
            colorPicker.supportsAlpha = false
            self.delegate = presentController as? OBColorPickerDelegate
            colorPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            presentController.present(colorPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On dismiss applying color to imageview with below code,

```
let imageView = StickerImageView() // StickerImageView is custom imageview
imageView.tintColor = color
```

then try to get tintColor by below code in StickerImageView class,

```
if let color = self.tintColor {
               //Color I got here is gay only for iOS 17
}
```

What can be the issue and please help me to solve it.

Tried converting uiextendedgraycolorspace to RGB but it creates only gray color

Answer (score 0):

> *It would be helpful to attach the relevant code snippets  where you are working with colors and applying them to a `UIImageView`* when posting a your question

**Override `tintColor` in `StickerImageView`**

In your `StickerImageView` class, you can override the `tintColor` property to perform custom handling:

```
override var tintColor: UIColor! {
    didSet {
       
        print("New TintColor: \(tintColor)")
    }
}
```

This allows you to inspect and potentially modify the `tintColor` behavior within your custom `StickerImageView`.try to change the color

**Or Temporary Workaround:**

As a temporary workaround, you might consider storing the selected color separately in your `StickerImageView` class and applying it manually when needed. This bypasses the issue of the `tintColor` not being retained.

```
var selectedColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        // Apply the color 
        self.tintColor = selectedColor
    }
}
```

I've Improved Appling color context, please consider doing it this way  here's a revised version of your code with some modifications and additional comments for clarity:

```
// Present the UIColorPickerViewController
let colorPicker = UIColorPickerViewController()
colorPicker.delegate = self
colorPicker.dismissDelegate = self
colorPicker.selectedColor = selectedColor ?? .black
colorPicker.supportsAlpha = false
colorPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
present(colorPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Handle color selection in the delegate method
extension YourViewController: UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        // Dismiss the color picker
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        // Apply the selected color to the StickerImageView
        if let selectedColor = viewController.selectedColor {
            // Convert the color to the RGB color space before setting it
            let rgbColor = selectedColor.converted(to: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB), intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil)
            
            // Set the color on your StickerImageView
            yourStickerImageView.tintColor = rgbColor
        }
    }

    func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        // Optional: Handle color selection updates if needed
    }
}

// In your StickerImageView class, override the tintColor property for debugging
class StickerImageView: UIImageView {
    override var tintColor: UIColor! {
        didSet {
            // Optional: Print the new tintColor for debugging
            print("New TintColor: \(tintColor)")
        }
    }
}
```

However i think your are facing a color space conversion issue from your description  when trying to apply a picked color . You can convert the color to the desired color space before applying it to the `tintColor` . You can make an extension to convert the color to the desired color space:

```
import UIKit
    
    extension UIColor {
        func convertToSRGB() -> UIColor? {
            guard let ciColor = self.cgColor.converted(to: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB), intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil) else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: ciColor)
        }
    }
    
    // usage
    let pickedColor: UIColor = // color picked from UIColorPickerViewController
    if let sRGBColor = pickedColor.convertToSRGB() {
        imageView.tintColor = sRGBColor
    }
```

Above extension method `convertToSRGB` attempts to convert the color to the sRGB color space. You can then set the converted color as the `tintColor` for your `UIImageView`.

Note: color space conversions can sometimes lead to subtle changes in appearance, especially if the original color was outside the sRGB color space

**Updated answer**

It seems there might be a discrepancy in the color spaces when setting and retrieving the tintColor . try explicitly converting the color to the desired color space, ensuring consistency . try this

```
if let color = self.tintColor {
    let sRGBColor = color.converted(to: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB), intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil)
    
}
```

Or try to print the color information before and after setting the tintColor and see if there are any discrepancies.

```
print("Before setting tintColor: \(color)")
self.tintColor = color
print("After setting tintColor: \(self.tintColor)")
```

Also If `StickerImageView` is a custom implementation, ensure that it doesn't interfere with the color space

If above didn't work out for you and the issue is specific to iOS 17, verify that there are no known issues or updates related to color handling in that iOS version. You can check Apple's release notes.

**Update after debug Info**

This change in color space might be due to the nature of the color you are assigning or a conversion that is happening when you set the `tintColor`. it seems that when you set the `tintColor`, the system is converting the color to this extended gray color space. So we If you want to maintain the RGB color space, you may need to ensure that the color you are setting for the `tintColor` is represented in the RGB color space. Or , you can explicitly convert the color to the desired color space before setting it. Here is an Example :

converting the color to the sRGB color space before setting the `tintColor`

```
if let color = self.tintColor {
    let sRGBColor = color.converted(to: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB), intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil)
    self.tintColor = sRGBColor
    print("After setting tintColor: \(self.tintColor)")
}
```

This way, you explicitly control the color space of the `tintColor` and can ensure it remains in the RGB model

Comment: This doesn't work, 
There is no issue while applying it, but when getting tintColor from UIImageView by imageView.tintColor then it always gives gray color.

Is there any other way ?

Comment: @MansiGolakiya Please attach relevant code snippets to your question.

Comment: Done, Edited the question.

Comment: @MansiGolakiya Thank you , I've added an update to my answer please check it out

Comment: @MohamdImran Still not solved by new solution.

Comment: @MansiGolakiya  did you try to print color info ? if yes what did it give you

Comment: Yes,
With solution you provided : kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.328699 0.328699 0.328699 0.8 
Without it : UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0.328699 0.8

Comment: @MansiGolakiya Thank you I've updated my answer again please check it

Comment: Still this doesn't work as color I got from color picker is already in kCGColorSpaceModelRGB color space

Comment: @MansiGolakiya Hmm ,can you Ensure that the alpha channel of the color is set appropriately. A low alpha value (e.g., close to 0) can result in a faded or gray appearance. use this 
`if let color = self.tintColor {
    print("Alpha: \(CGColorGetAlpha(color))")
}`

Or Instead of relying on the color picker, try explicitly setting the color using known RGB components like this 
`let knownRGBColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
self.tintColor = knownRGBColor
`
check result if it's expected color

Comment: @MansiGolakiya check my answer please , I've added Temporary Workaround

Comment: @MohamdImran I tried for purple color by let knownRGBColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) self.tintColor = knownRGBColor, still issue generated.

Comment: @MansiGolakiya please check my answer the top part I've added a new workaround

Comment: New TintColor: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0.559547 0.8)
Still getting this

Comment: @MansiGolakiya can you tell me what the app is designed to do like is it some photo editing app ,etc ...

Comment: It is template maker app